# Loop through text file and execute If Then statement for each line with bash

Tags: bash, loops, nested

I have a command that lists the full 8 level deep path of all folders we are backing up.
I also have a command that enumerates all 8 level deep folders on the system. 
Both of these are stored as variables in a bash script.

I'm trying to get a loop together that takes file 1 and uses the first line entry as a variable in an `if`/`then`/`else`, and then moves onwards to through the end of the file.

I've tried so many things but its beyond my skillset to provide an example that won't confuse the reader of this post.

```
TempFile1=/ifs/data/scripts/ConfigMonitor/TempFile1.txt
TempFile2=/ifs/data/scripts/ConfigMonitor/TempFile2.txt
find /ifs/*/*/backup -maxdepth 4 -mindepth 4 -type d > $TempFile1
isi snapshot schedules list -v | grep Path: | awk '{print $2}' > $TempFile2

list line 1 on $TempFile1
Grep for line 1 within $TempFile2
if result yielded then
  echo found
else
  echo fullpath not being backed up
fi
```

Comment: BashFAQ #1 is on-point: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: As an aside, `grep | awk` is almost always silly; `awk` can do everything `grep` can, making connecting them together unnecessary. `awk '/Path:/ {print $2}'`, in the immediate case.

Comment: On a different point -- if you want to be able to test set membership in a performant manner (O(1)) in bash, you might want to look into associative arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use Grep's -f Flag

grep(1) says:

```sh
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

Therefore, the following should work:

```sh
grep -f patterns_to_match.txt file_to_examine.txt
```

### Faster Reporting

Another way to think about this is that you can ask GNU grep to show you all the matches:

```sh
echo 'Lines that match a pattern in your pattern file.'
grep -f patterns_to_match.txt file_to_examine.txt
```

and then show you all the lines that don't match any of the patterns:

```sh
echo 'Lines that do not match any patterns in your pattern file.'
grep -f patterns_to_match.txt -v file_to_examine.txt
```

This is likely to be faster and more efficient than looping through the file one line at a time in Bash. You may or may not get similar results with a grep other than GNU grep; while the -f and -v flags are specified by POSIX, I only tested it against GNU grep 2.16, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: as As much as i use grep, i cant say i thought of this.  Grep -f then -v to the target of what is being backed up shows me everything that is NOT backed up. This is much simpler and also outputs the full paths of what to add that was missed.  Thank you so much for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

This should iterate through Tempfile1.txt and grep for the line in TempFile2.txt.

```
while read line; do
    if grep $line /path/to/TempFile2.txt > /dev/null
    then
       echo "Found $line"
    else
       echo "Did not find $line"
    fi
done < Tempfile1.txt
```

Tempfile1.txt:

```
a
b
c
```

Tempfile2.txt

```
b
d
z
```

Output:

```
Did not find a
Found b
Did not find c
```